# Using Integration by Parts to find leading order approximation of exponential integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, laplace-method

I'm trying to understand how finding leading order approximation of exponential integrals.

Here is my integral: $$\int^{+\infty}_0 e^{-xt}\ln(1+t^2)dt$$

I need to use Integration by parts to then find the leading order asymptotic approximation and using the remainder in integral form, showing that the approximation is in fact asymptotic.

(EDIT) This is what I have tried:

Integration by Parts gives:

$$[\frac{e^{-xt}\ln(1+t^2)}{-x}]^{+\infty}_0 + x^{-1}\int^{+\infty}_0e^{-xt}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt$$

The boundary term vanishes and the Remainder is the second term.

Then I show that the Remainder is Asymptotic:
$$|R(x)| \leq x^{-1}\int^{+\infty}_0|e^{-xt}||\frac{2t}{1+t^2}|dt \leq x^{-1}[\ln(1+t^2)]^{+\infty}_0$$

But I find a divergence.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please show what exactly you already calculated, and where the problems are.

Comment: @MartinR done, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly derived that
$$
 f(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \ln(1+t^2) \, dt
 = \frac 2x \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \frac{t}{1+t^2} \, dt 
$$
for $x > 0$. This does not yet reveal the asymptotic behavior for $x \to \infty$, so let's integrate by parts again:
$$
 f(x) = -\frac{2}{x^2} e^{-xt} \frac{t}{1+t^2} \big|_{t_0}^{t=\infty}
+ \frac{2}{x^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \, dt \, .
$$
Again the first part vanishes, and we have
$$
 f(x) = \frac{2}{x^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \, dt \, .
$$
But we don't give up and integrate once more:
$$
\begin{align}
 f(x) &= -\frac{2}{x^3} e^{-xt} \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \big|_{t_0}^{t=\infty}
+ \frac{2}{x^3} \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \frac{2t(t^2-3)}{(1+t^2)^3} \, dt \\
&= \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{4}{x^3} \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \frac{t(t^2-3)}{(1+t^2)^3} \, dt \\
&=: \frac{2}{x^3} + R(x) \, .
\end{align}
$$
That looks promising! $\frac{t(t^2-3)}{(1+t^2)^3}$ is bounded on $\Bbb R$ (the denominator has no zeros and a higher degree than the numerator). Therefore, with some constant $M > 0$
$$
 |R(x)| \le \frac{4M}{x^3} \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \, dt
= \frac{4M}{x^4}
$$
and we have shown that
$$
 f(x) = \frac{2}{x^3} + O\left( \frac{1}{x^4} \right)
$$
for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh I see, so we keep on integrating by parts until we can find a remainder that is bounded?

Comment: @bsaoptima: All terms are bounded in the above calculation. Here you keep integrating until you get a sum of a “leading term” and something else which grows more slowly. That works in this particular case, I don't think that there is a general recipe for it.

Comment: Ok now I understand, since the boundary terms kept on vanishing we continue integrating by parts.

Answer (score 2):

For the antiderivative, using integration by parts, we have
$$\int e^{-t x} \log \left(t^2+1\right)\,dx=-\frac 1x e^{-t x} \log \left(t^2+1\right)+\frac 2x\int \frac{t }{t^2+1}\,e^{-t x}\,dt$$
Using the bounds, the first term is $0$ and what remains is the calculation of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t }{t^2+1}\,e^{-t x}\,dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{t }{(t+i)(t-i)}\,e^{-t x}\,dt$$

Use partial fraction decomposition and then two obvious changes of variable; the integral is finite.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I don't really understand what to do with the changes of variables, my lecture notes are not very informative.

Comment: @bsaoptima. You face two simple integrals. In thé worst case, show thé convergene

Answer (score 0):

It's been shown that $I\sim2/x^3$ which is the leading order approximation, but for your interest, a complete asymptotic expansion can also be found.
$$\ln(1+t^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{2n+2}$$
By [Watson's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma),
$$\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty}\ln(1+t^2)e^{-xt}\ dt\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(2n+3)}{n+1}\frac{1}{x^{2n+3}}}$$
as $x\to+\infty$.